# permissions of documents in a Node app

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have a node app that needs several user permission levels, this is an event app so we need permissions for a lot of pages and things. I know how to authenticate a user with passport but cant find a great way to do permissions, does anyone know of a library or a way using passport to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an if-statement for the permission levels and and set the conditions to what ever conditions you need for a certain permission level.

You can check out this simplified example I have that I used myself in that way when creating a twitch bot:

```
if (username == "admin"){
    // admin
    var userLevel = 4;
} else if (username == "supermod"){
    // supermod
    userLevel = 3;
} else if (username === "mod"){
    // moderator
    userLevel = 2;
} else if (username == "banned user") {
   // banned user
   var userLevel = -1;
} else {
   // default user
   userLevel = 1;
}
```

You can generally replace now the condition in the if-statement so that it fits your needs and send it to a database, or check the userlevel new on every usage.